# PHP can not be started

Tags: php

I ran the following command:

```
/usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm start
```

but the output is:

```
Usage: php-fpm [-n] [-e] [-h] [-i] [-m] [-v] [-t] [-p <prefix> ] [-c <file>] [-d foo[=bar]] [-y <file>]
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -v               Version number
  -p, --prefix <dir>
                   Specify alternative prefix path to FastCGI process manager (default: /usr/local/webserver/php).
  -y, --fpm-config <file>
                   Specify alternative path to FastCGI process manager config file.
  -t, --test       Test FPM configuration and exit
```

Is there anyone who has knowledge about this problem? Any advice appreciated!

Updated:

OS : CentOS 5.6
PHP: 5.3.6

I tried `/usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm` and it works! Why?

I installed PHP with its source code.

Comment: AFAIK PHP-FPM is not a service/daemon. Why are you expecting `start` to work?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: it is a daemon

Comment: @Pekka: obviously he is trying to start php-fpm daemon ;-)

Comment: @zerkms No it's not. It is *used* as a daemon but it is not one by itself. It needs a host, hence why he is expecting "start" to run it. This should be achieved by `services`. Eg; `service php-fpm start`, which again, doesn't send a command to PHP-FPM but `services`.

Comment: @Christian Sciberra: `services` is one of many possible ways to demonize it. OP just did not know that, and you all start being that "smart guys", instead of trying to help him.

Comment: @Foredoomed: Please add the distribution you're using, the design how you would like to make php-fpm work with your webserver, the actual webserver you're using, a reference to the source of your php-fpm, your php version and if you followed some tutorial/guide as well the link to that resource.

Comment: For the people who haven't had their coffee yet, this appears to be a problem with php-fpm's documentation, since it clearly states that you run `php-fpm start` from the $PATH (which /sbin/php-fpm would have been, if Foredoomed hadn't compiled it with such a wacky PREFIX).  PHP's documentation for it has a comment explaining how to create an init script to set it up, since it apparently does not come with one by default.  Someone who has actually gotten php-fpm to work despite the broken documentation is going to have to say what they did to start it.

Comment: FYI @DerfK, there's nothing wacky about /usr/local... it's actually the proper way to do it per the hier man page, it's just that linux doesn't enforce this at all, and programs can be installed pretty much anywhere... FreeBSD's ports system installs all ports into /usr/local/* replacing /etc and /sbin and /usr/bin with the /usr/local equivalents.  from http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier:  /usr/local: This is where programs which are local to the site typically go

Comment: @zerkms - Me the smart guy? Wasn't you the one blurting that PHP-FPM is a daemon? I simply told him `start` won't work with it. It was a comment, not an answer. You, on the other hand, went ahead explaining  how start will magically work by putting the program name in an init script, without even explaining why. Stop being daft.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is with the command you called:

```
/usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm start
```

The `start` part of it is not part of it's switches/parameters, so `php-fpm` gives you the usage information so you can actually look for what you tried to do, to correct your command call.

What do you wanted to do?

Are you looking how to configure your webserver to use the PHP-FPM implementation instead of FASTCGI?

Comment: omg, guys, he **wanted to start php-fpm daemon**

Comment: @zerkms: Which would not work for CLI. Hence my question: "What do you wanted to do?"

Comment: where do you see php cli? He is interacting with php-fpm

Comment: @zerkms: He is running the command in the shell, that is where I see CLI (Command Line Interface).

Comment: I know what CLI means, but he is trying to run php-fpm. Isn't that obvious for you? Have you ever worked with php-fpm?

Comment: @zerkms: No it's not obvious to me. Have you ever worked with Foredoomed?

Comment: No, I haven't. But just believe me that OP wants to start php-fpm daemon, ok? Do you have another thoughts when you see `php-fpm start` rather than attempt of starting php-fpm daemon?

Comment: I believe OP was very concrete and asked specifically about the problem why that command displays the usage information. At least until more information is being provided, like the reference OP is referring to and the server configuration.

Comment: Come on, stop being so pedantic

Comment: @zerkms - He's working on what he's got. Last time I assumed I knew what the OP wanted, I got slapped with a -5 score just because I assumed the wrong answer. If you don't want to be pedantic, feel free to run the risk. Leave the rest of us out of it.

Comment: Well you already gave the hint to `/etc/init.d/php-fpm start`, didn't you? So what to argue about?

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: thanks for -1. So my answer **is wrong**?

Comment: @zerkms: No reason to downvote my answer. It's not wrong neither.

Comment: @hakre: it doesn't help to start daemon (that is what OP wanted). And it contains only questions that would be better placed at question comments, since they doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Oh well, you're concerned about getting a downvote on your answer you think that isn't wrong (it did not help the OP), but you actually feel well with giving a downvote on an answer that (might) not help either. Hmm. Looks like you judge different on others than on yourself. Or actually, that you need to pass on badness just because it happened to you.

Comment: @zerkms - Huh, who said I down-voted your answer?

Comment: *omg, guys, he wanted to start php-fpm daemon* Me too! I just wanted to **view a youtube video from my Nokia 1110i**. But sadly it didn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer the question based on a small (but major) assumption and not commment first because it may get lost in the bickering going on in comments.

It *appears* as though Foredoomed may be on FreeBSD, and has installed from ports.  The question is lacking this useful information.  On FreeBSD, there is no init.d and ports installed using `/usr/local` which is a major clue based on what I've seen so far.

So with that said, try this:

Edit `/etc/rc.conf` as root and add `php_fpm_enable=”YES”` to it, then save and close.

When you're ready to run php-fpm again, you start it using the rc.d scripts.  As it's an installed program, it is not in `/etc/rc.d`, but in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`:

Run the following: `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php-fpm start`